# snowflake load csv file option not available or any file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to upload a .csv file but there is no option to load or may be I'm not finding it. I watched many tutorials but the UI that they had is different to mine and I'm not able to change to the other UI like others that has load options. [image]

this above picture is the UI that I have, and am not able to shift to another one as the classic UI button is missing. Am I missing anything here or the load option is missing temporarily?

Answer (score 0):

The Load option is currently disabled and currently we are working on adding this feature to the Snowsight.
Also the classic Web UI is disabled for all new trial accounts.
However there is a workaround as of now.
Can you add ?disableDirectLogin=true to the URL you are currently using and let me know the results.

e.g. https://xxxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com/console/login?disableDirectLogin=true

This will get you the classic Web UI and you can use the load button in thus UI.
Hope this helps.